# Windows 10 - All sound cuts out and emits loud buzz after 4-6 seconds

Tags: windows, audio, dell-xps

Playing any sound on my Dell XPS Windows 10 laptop works exactly as normal for 4-6 seconds, then cuts out and is replaced by a loud buzzing sound for about one second. Then sound can be played again for another 4-6 seconds, at which point the error recurs.
On YouTube, after the error occurs twice, the video stops playing ("An error occurred. Please try again later").

Also, the "beep" noise emitted when, e.g., changing the volume or clicking out of a window when doing so is not permitted, is also replaced with a quiet buzzing sound (immediately, not after 4-6 seconds).

I have tried completely removing the Realtek Audio drivers, replacing them with an older version (2.81 rather than 2.82), and changing the default audio format. The error occurs regardless of whether I am using the built-in speakers or headphones. I have also tried reinstalling Windows, so this does not seem to be a software issue.

Any ideas what exactly is happening or how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Try running the built-in Dell diagnostics.

Comment: I tried that and it installed some new audio drivers, but that didn't solve the issue

Comment: try https://www.dell.com/community/General/XPS-13-9343-Audio-driver-problems-in-Windows-10/td-p/4627566/highlight/true. this is unlikely to help, but read https://www.drivethelife.com/windows-drivers/dell-xps-15-9560-drivers-windows-10-download-update.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to recover normal sound by using a Bluetooth speaker (the issue, apparently, is a problem with my motherboard's integrated sound card).